# How to set x-axis labels with ios charts

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios-charts

I've recently started using the ios charts library and am having trouble finding information on how to manipulate the x-axis with the swift3 update.

What I want to do is label the x-axis with time values, e.g. 2:03:00, 2:03:01, 2:03:02, etc. In the tutorials I find online, this seems to be very easy; many of them use months of the year as the x-axis label.

However, in the swift3 update, charts now initializes values with x and y values, and I am not sure how to use labels in this version of the library. Does anyone know how to create labels in charts with swift3?

Comment: Would this question/answer help? : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960302/how-to-add-labels-for-xaxis-for-barchartview-in-ios-charts)

Comment: Please consider to comment about why you are votting down this question

Answer (score 69):

**Proper Solution for X-Axis String labels in Swift 3+**

```
let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months)
    barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
```

Comment: granularity will set the proper position for xValues under the bar lines.

Comment: I use your code to show the xValues but It shows month by alternate basis

Comment: Doesn't this rely on the assumption that you have data for each month? If you don't have data for, say, April, wouldn't the value formatter never pass the index in that corresponds to April / wouldn't the April label never be generated?

Comment: Thanks man you literally saved me. I spent 2 hrs banging my head.

Answer (score 16):

Create a class like this:

```
    import Foundation
    import Charts

    @objc(BarChartFormatter)
    class ChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter{

    let months: [String] = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return months[Int(value)]
    }

}
```

Set the x-Axis like this:

```
    let xAxis = XAxis()
    let chartFormatter = ChartFormatter()
    
    for i in index {
        chartFormatter.stringForValue(Double(i), axis: xAxis)
    }
    
    xAxis.valueFormatter = chartFormatter
    chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxis.valueFormatter
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with Pie Charts? since xAxis is not a thing in pie charts and the labels initializer was also removed

Comment: Excuse me, I don't now  :(

Comment: it took me a while, but in the newest Charts library version, the Pie Chart has a new entry initializer named pieChartDataEntry which takes a label as an argument
` let entry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(entryValue), label: label)`

Comment: I've used this solution but it didn't help me. Could you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618636/how-to-add-string-labels-xaxis-labels-to-horizontal-bar-in-charts-framework)?

Comment: Amir, I'll see my project, I forgot it. @AmirShabani

Comment: @HamedAkhlaghi I found the answer, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: was my answer helpful? @AmirShabani

Comment: I had a mistake on my code, by the way, I used something like your codes

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think this solution actually works. Does anyone know why stringForValue is called in a for loop without doing anything else? That method seems to just return a string and doesn't explicitly set the labels.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 5.5**

I'm having pretty good results using standard `DateFormatter()` I'm converting UNIX timestamp to format day.month

```
final class XAxisNameFormatter: NSObject, AxisValueFormatter {
    
    func stringForValue( _ value: Double, axis _: AxisBase?) -> String {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM"
        
        return formatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
self.lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = XAxisNameFormater()
self.lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

Comment: Perfect Solution.

Answer (score 6):

I propose to use more flexible and pretty solution. You should have a formatter class like this:

```
final class MonthNameFormater: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    func stringForValue( _ value: Double, axis _: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return Calendar.current.shortMonthSymbols[Int(value)]
    }
}
```

Set up this type to your `barChartView`:

```
barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = MonthNameFormater()
barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

As a result you will have: `Jan, Feb, ..., Dec` 
In addition if you want to change presentation kind you should change shortMonthSymbols with some other: `monthSymbols, veryShortMonthSymbols, standaloneMonthSymbols`

Comment: One thing I don't quite understand about the latest version of the library is: what if we want to have labels for months for which no data is entered? Say there is no data for March but we still want to show "Mar" in the chart. Wouldn't the "value" in stringForValue never equal 2 (March)?

Comment: I was way over thinking this problem. This solution is so simple! Thank you for this!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating your own formatter for the time. Below I mention sample code for that for your reference.

```
    public class DateValueFormatter: NSObject, AxisValueFormatter {
    private let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    }

    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
    }
}
```

To set your value just use below code.

```
self.yourChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = DateValueFormatter()
self.yourChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems creating the class as the previous answers

> 'No type or protocol named 'IChartAxisValueFormatter'

I removed the `NSObject` inheritance and left only `IAxisValueFormatter` like here:

```
final class XAxisNameFormater: IAxisValueFormatter {.....
```