# Don't show month in Chart in swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I want to display the chart in **Swift 3** but why the month name is not showing, is there anyone with coding?

```
@IBOutlet var utilizationChart: LineChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
        let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 18.0, 19.0, 21.0, 24.0, 30.0, 16.0]

        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)

        utilizationChart.chartDescription?.text = ""
        utilizationChart.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        utilizationChart.noDataText = "No chart data available"

}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        utilizationChart.delegate = self
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

        for i in 0..<values.count {
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Utilization")
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
        utilizationChart.data = lineChartData

}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZqOf.jpg]

Comment: don't understand where you want to display month?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049188/how-to-add-strings-on-x-axis-in-ios-charts ?